# Clicking link using capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a link that I need to click with capybara:

```
<div class="x-header x-floats x-push one-line ng-scope">
  <div class="left">
    <h1>Users</h1>
  </div>

  <span class="hint--left" data-hint="Create User">
    <a class="x-round-button icon-plus" ng-tap="url('new')"></a>
  </span>
</div>
```

I need to click the a with a class of x-round-button but I can't seem to find the right way to do so. I want to avoid using xpath if possible. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like

```
page.find('.x-round-button').click
```